# flask run importerror raised

Tags: python, flask

I was running flask app using app.run till now. But when I was trying to use flask-migrate, it throws an error when I am trying 'flask run'

File directory is like this:

```
project/
├─ project/
│  ├─ static/
│  │  ├─ app.js
│  ├─ templates/
│  │  ├─ base.html
│  ├─ routes.py
│  ├─ __init__.py
│  ├─ forms.py
│  ├─ models.py
├─ run.py
├─ setup.py
├─ MANIFEST.in
```

I was following documentation, but it did not work. 'python run.py' works but 'flask run' is not working.

```
export FLASK_APP=project
export FLASK_ENV=development

Error: While importing 'project', an ImportError was raised.
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: This questions is lacking a lot of details that are likely very useful.  What IDE are you using?  How are you running it?  Have you tried running directly from a command line?

Answer (score -1):

try, to change the `FLASK_APP` value

```
export FLASK_APP=run
...
```

As far as I understood from the Flask docs - the `FLASK_APP` value needs to be the same as the "main app" filename (just without the `.py`)

docs for ref: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/quickstart/#a-minimal-application3

Comment: I tried, but still same error. 'Error: While importing 'run', an ImportError was raised.'

Comment: so maybe just rename the `run.py` to `app.py` and forget about `FLASK_APP`

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/quickstart/#:~:text=Application%20Discovery%20Behavior,for%20more%20details.

Comment: still got the same error...